# Parallel line construction without square root

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given a line defined by two points having rational coordinates, is it possible to construct a parallel line at a given rational distance to the first line, using only $+$, $-$, $*$, $/$, i.e. without $\surd$?

In other words, usually one would construct a parallel line by taking the two points as a vector, normalise it, make it perpendicular, scalar multiply by the distance, add the resulting vector to one of the two original points. That normalisation employs square root, is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: Is the required separation distance given?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes, and it's also rational. Now I see what you probably meant, see the edit.

Comment: For the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$If we have the line defined by $y_1=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}(x-x_0)+y_0$, where $x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1\in\mathbb{Q}$. Using only rationals, can construct parallel lines of the form $y_2=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}(x-x_0)+y_0+\frac{a}{b}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. The distance would then be $\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2-\left(\frac{y_1-y_0}{2(x_1-x_0)}\right)^2}$. Thus, we can only construct parallel lines with distance of the latter form. I.e; if the distance is $\frac{m}{n}$, $m$ and $n$ must be square integers.

Comment: Draw a perpendicular line and than on it the desired ratio.

Comment: @Graviton Not sure I understood correctly: if the distance is $p^2/q^2$, where $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ then the $\sqrt{...}$ expression of yours always evaluates to a rational number? How does it help with the "sqrt-less" construction? You mean if $m, n$ are square integers then the square root in the normalisation in the procedure I gave is always rational?

Comment: @EcirHana It depends what you mean by 'construct'. But assuming that you are only allowed to use elementary operations **without** roots, then you cannot construct a parallels at *any* rational distance. Only distances at the squares of rationals.

Comment: @Graviton ...because the square root then cancels out?

Comment: Your use of the tag `geometric-construction` (and the word "construct") is confusing, but it seems you're asking whether it's possible to express the equation of the line you describe using only rational coefficients. Well, as your analysis suggests, the length of the line's direction vector is always involved, so you'll get rational coefficients only if that length is rational. Scaling by the denominator of that rational gives an integer, so that the given line must have a "slope triangle" whose sides are a [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) of integers.

Comment: I can answer your question with a ruler whose length is marked with rational numbers. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @Saeed Yes, but please note that the original line length might not be rational.

Comment: @EcirHana, you could consider it cancelling out, certainly

Answer (score 0):

I will assume we have a ruler with some rational numbers marked along its length.

I will also assume we have the two points on the cartesian plane, with $x$ and $y$ axes.

Let the two given points be $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, and let the required distance between the parallel lines be $d$. Here is the procedure:

1. On the $x$ axis, mark points $A(y_1-y_2 , 0)$ and $B(y_2-y_1 , 0)$
2. On the $y$ axis, mark points $C(0 , x_1-x_2)$ and $D(0 , x_2-x_1)$
3. Draw $AC$ and $BD$ (and extend them if necessary) and let them meet the (if necessary, extended) initially given line at $E$ and $F$, respectively.
4. Using the ruler, mark points $G$ and $H$ on extensions of $AE$ and $BF$ at distance $d$ from $E$ and $F$, respectively.
5. Draw $GH$. It is the required line.

The following figure visualizes this procedure. The two given points are marked with + signs.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! However, now that I see what you meant by "marked ruler", I'm afraid this is not what I'm after. I very sorry, I know I said it would be acceptable and I don't know what to do now. The problem is that in order to "apply" this ruler you are in fact using $\surd$ because it is equivalent to construct an intersection between the ray AE and the circle at E with radius d. In other words, it doesn't say how to "align" the ruler to the ray.

Comment: @EcirHana Thank you for your comment. I disagree: the above procedure avoids the use of compass (hence avoiding the square root). Note that when we use a compass to find an intersection point, we have no idea about the *direction* along which the point lies. In contrast, in the above procedure we construct the direction. In other words, I found a route and said "drive in this route a distance $d$". This is basically different from the compass problem. Besides, if we have a target distance, and we cannot use a ruler to measure it nor a compass, then how else is it possible to build it?